# Ember.js: Relationship between view input and model

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, ember-data

I'm brand new to Ember.js, but well-versed in MVC and Backbone (even cocoa and smalltalk), but for some reason, Ember's insistence on its highly-obscured and inconsistent API is shielding me from understanding 1) binding and 2) how that relates to persisting records.

I have a view that has an input. I know that. I have a model that belongs to a controller. I know that. I don't understand how the view knows (or is supposed to know) about the controller, and I don't understand how the model gets the text I type into the view when I'm ready to push it to the backend (ostensibly with `.save()`). These are supposed to be boilerplate style things that Ember breathlessly abstracts away, but I find I'm having to go through the Ember.js source just to understand what the heck is happening.

I've read the docs, and their examples are so contrived as to be unusable (featuring only the most basic examples, which is pointless when we're talking about "ambitious web apps", which ember purports to *be* for).

It should be noted that we are using ember-data in house, and this particular route has multiple views, controllers and models.

Answer (score 1):

So let's say you have an input in the index template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
     {{input type="text" value=name}}
</script>
```

Ember automatically binds the `App.IndexController` to this template and the name property of the controller to the value property of the input field.  As the value is changed in the input, it'll automatically update in the controller.  When you're ready to save it in the model you can access the property in a action.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        save:function() {
            var name = this.get('name');
            var model = this.store.createRecord('item');
            item.set('name',name);
            item.save();
        }
    }
});
```

This will trigger a post request to `/items` to store the item.

If you have a more specific example in mind, I can try to show you how that works.

Comment: What if the controller is not part of the route? That is, it's a controller that lives inside of another controller?

Comment: Where would the second controller come from?  If you haven't already, I would really suggest installing [Ember Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/) in Google Chrome.  In the View Tree, you can see all the different views in your app and the associated controller.

Comment: The second (or containing) controller is, I believe, instantiated by the route. I'll try the inspector.

Comment: Yes, the main controller would come from the route.  But where is the subcontroller coming from and what would it link to?

Comment: The sub controller is instantiated by the view, which is instantiated in handlebars vis-a-vis `{{view App.Foo}}`. In `App.Foo`'s `init` function, I have `this.set('controller', App.BarController.create());`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually create a view.  Ember will automatically create one for you and if you need to override some aspect of it, you can just define it in your js and make any modifications you need.  Views don't have their own controller.  They have the controller of the current context.  So if you have a view in the index route, it'll still reference the IndexController.  Check out this [comparison table](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_comparison-table) to see exactly refers to what. If you need a section with its own controller, use a render helper.

Comment: Is that not what `{{view ... }}` is? A render helper?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50649/discussion-between-nicholasjohn16-and-dclowd9901)